# Send PHP Email with out mail() function

Tags: php, email

I have a web account on Windows using PHP with Godaddy.  Godaddy want their users to use gdform.php when I would rather use some my own custom php script.

Is it possible to send PHP mail with out the `mail()` function?

Comment: Have you tried it? I've got no experience with GoDaddy but my first port to call would be to try sending an email with the native `mail()` function and see if it works. Why don't you want to follow GoDaddy's advice anyway? They must have their reasons...

Comment: I have tried sending email using mail() and it doesn't work.  The problem is that I have to do more legwork with their custom email scripts as opposed to working with my own script that I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

http://swiftmailer.org/

Both these are super-powerful mailing classes for PHP.  I use PHPMailer to send out 30,000+ emails per day on my company's online application.

Here's the thing though, I have several simple contact forms on small customer websites hosted by GoDaddy that are using php's mail() without fail.  They may tell you not to use it, but it's sure working just fine for me....Or perhaps the Windows servers aren't running PHPMail.  As an aside, I'm getting as far away from GoDaddy as quickly as possible.....

Answer (score 1):

Try [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) with native SMTP. And there are other pure PHP implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.introduction.html), Great features and easy to use, although I've heard stuff about it's numerous bugs but I'm not sure how much those rumors are true.